# XML: Add Child for every Product - Not Working (PHP)

Tags: php, xml

I want to add to every product the plattform by getting the plattform from the title or the url. But the problem is that the array in which I save the plattform is not as big as the product list. But that can't be!
Because in every case I push a value into the array... So it should be equal big!

But it isn't... Also the code IS NOT ADDING the Child to the XML. But I don't know why... How can I solve that?

Code:

```
function isContaining($searches, $titleTag, $urlTag, $productTag, $path){

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->load($path);
$root = $dom->documentElement;

$markerTitle = $root->getElementsByTagName($titleTag);
$markerURL = $root->getElementsByTagName($urlTag);

$plat = array();

for($i = $markerTitle->length - 1; $i >= 0 ; $i--){

    $title = $markerTitle->item($i)->textContent;
    $url = $markerURL->item($i)->textContent;

    $size = count($searches);

    for($j = 0; $j < $size; $j++){
        if(stripos($title, $searches[$j])){
            if($j > 4){
                array_push($plat, "PlayStation");
            }elseif($j < 5){
                array_push($plat, $searches[$j]);
            }else{
                array_push($plat, "Nothing");
            }
        }elseif(stripos($url, $searches[$j])){
            if($j > 4){
                array_push($plat, "PlayStation");
            }elseif($j < 5){
                array_push($plat, $searches[$j]);
            }else{
                array_push($plat, "Nothing");
            }
        }
    }
}

array_reverse($plat);
print_r($plat);
$count = 0;

foreach($root->getElementsByTagName($productTag) as $product){
    $newElement = $dom->createElement('plat', $plat[$count]);
    $product->appendChild($newElement);
    $count = $count + 1;
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <name>Final Fantasy VII Steam</name>
    <desc>Den Rollenspiel-Klassiker FINAL FANTASY VII gibt es jetzt für den PC, mit brandneuen Online-Features!</desc>
    <price>11.69</price>
    <price_base>12.99</price_base>
    <link>https://de.gamesplanet.com/game/final-fantasy-vii-download--1001-1</link>
    <publisher>Eidos - Square Enix</publisher>
    <category>RPG (Rollenspiel)</category>
    <ean/>
    <packshot>https://de.gamesplanet.com/acache/10/01/1/de/packshot-770bf6d03800b87dc0f9509f21e8d423.jpg</packshot>
  </product>
```

Greetings

Comment: It looks like you're using `stripos()` with a loose comparison. A zero value for the index (string found at first position) would be incorrectly false.  Use `if (stripos($title, $searches[$j]) !== false)` for strict comparison to false.  But I'm not certain this is the cause of your issue or your only issue.

Comment: Also you have no `else {}` case for the outer `if/elseif` structure so a non-match wouldn't be added to your array.

Comment: What do you mean with:

Also you have no else {} case for the outer if/elseif structure so a non-match wouldn't be added to your array.?

Comment: Beginning at `if(stripos($title, $searches[$j])){` you have `if/elseif` but you have no final `else` to catch strings that matched neither `$title` nor `$url`. It is possible that because you did not compare strictly to `!== false` that some nodes are falling through, not matching `$title` or `$url` and resulting in fewer array items than you expect.